# "Zu" without dative case

Tags: grammatical-case

I think the declination of the adjective in the following example is correct.

> Es wird uns ein großer Aufwand

Using the preposition "zu" usually requires the dative case. So why doesn't it here?:

> Es wird uns ein zu großer Aufwand

Comment: What kind of _dative_ are you missing? How do you think that sentence should be constructed?

Comment: zu groß = too big... no need for dative case...

Comment: In every German Grammar textbook I have seen you can read that "zu" ALWAYS takes the dative. Why doesn't zu groß? I accept it doesn't but would like to know why and if there are other examples of zu not needing the dative case.

Comment: My english is quite bad - what is "the think declination"? It seems to be sth different than the declination of think itself. Thanks.

Comment: @Shegit Brahm It was a typing error. Thank you very much for pointing it out. I have corrected the mistake in the OP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **preposition `zu`** requires the dative case. E.g. "Das Kind geht zur Schule" (... to school).

However, the **adverb `zu`**, which can be translated as "too", does not dictate which case should be used.

In the phrase "ein zu großer Aufwand", "zu" is not a preposition but an adverb that modifies the adjective "groß" ("too big"). The phrase is in the nominative case due to its function in the sentence, not because of the presence or absence of a preposition.

Answer (score 3):

- The preposition *zu* goes with dative; this rule has no exception
- Whenever *zu* is not a preposition, *zu* has no influence on the already determined case, as in the example you gave. But it *might* be dative:

> ...mit einem zu doofen Gegenbeispiel...

(the dative is now due to *mit*).